# How to apply crop_to_bounding_box in TensorFlow 2 to a symbolic tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have the following bit of code that is designed to find the first and last pixels with a pixel intensity of >= 25 and then crop to that bounding box:

```
white_pixels = tf.where(input_img >= 25)
first_white_pixel = white_pixels[:, 0]
first_white_pixel = tf.cast(first_white_pixel, dtype=tf.int32)
last_white_pixel = white_pixels[:, -1]
last_white_pixel = tf.cast(last_white_pixel, dtype=tf.int32)
cropped = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(input_img, first_white_pixel[0], 0, last_white_pixel[0] - first_white_pixel[0], 299)
```

However, I keep getting an error saying that the target_height in tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box must be above 0. In all my images, the result of last_white_pixel[0] - first_white_pixel[0] is definitely above 0. The code is executed as a symbolic tensor in TensorFlow 2.3 and works fine in a non-symbolic setting (for the lack of a better term).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake seems to have been a slicing error. Instead of writing

```
first_white_pixel = white_pixels[:, 0]
last_white_pixel = white_pixels[:, -1]
```

I should have written

```
first_white_pixel = white_pixels[0, :]
last_white_pixel = white_pixels[-1, :]
```